# How costly is casting in Kotlin?

Tags: casting, kotlin

In Kotlin, how costly is the casting of classes?

So for instance, let's have the following `Test` class

```
open class Test {
    open fun question() = "Basic question"
}
```

and 3 inheriting classes

```
class MathTest : Test() {
    override fun question() = "2+2=?"
}

class EnglishTest : Test() {
    override fun question() = "Who created SO?"
}

class HistoryTest: Test() {
    override fun question() = "When was SO created?"
}
```

How costly would it be to cast (for instance, let's say) 100 `Test` objects to either one of these 3, at runtime, in Android (and in general) ?

Comment: Not more than with Java.

Comment: near to nothing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336788/4265739

Comment: if I look at the documentation, casting could be possible for all: kotlin-js, kotlin-native and kotlin-jvm... I am only using kotlin-jvm and there a cast translates to the same as in Java (and for casting there exist already some microbenchmarks). Regarding kotlin-js and kotlin-native? Don't know how a cast is working there or whether it is even supported... would be nice if someone else could tell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I messed around a little bit with disassembling the generated bytecode, and except for one case, casting is identical to Java. The one case where it seems to be different is when using [the safe cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator), `as?`, like so:

```
val thing = "" as? Int
```

This generates equivalent bytecode to this Java code:

```
String _temp = "";
if (!(_temp instanceof Integer)) {
    _temp = null;
}
Integer thing = (Integer) _temp;
```

This makes it slightly more expensive than a regular cast in Java. However, there is no direct equivalent to this behavior in Java, short of writing a similar `if` statement anyways, so I think it's safe to say that **casting in Kotlin is no more expensive than casting in Java.**

Comment: Safe cast is separate though, it's more an extension of the existing cast.

Comment: @Zoe, yes, I make a note of that near the end of my answer.

Comment: *casting in Kotlin is no more expensive than casting in Java* -- this is not really an answer because OP did not ask about the cost relative to java

Comment: @TimCastelijns What metric would you prefer then? The exact time taken to cast would vary wildly depending on many different factors, so the best general way to quantify it in my opinion would be to compare it with Java.

Comment: I don't know, you should ask OP

Comment: I would definitely also link some microbenchmarks for Java... but I wonder whether casting is supported for kotlin-js and kotlin-native too and if so: how is it solved there or how is the impact there?

Comment: The OP did specify what to compare against and it wasn't Java. It was using `test.question()` where `test` is `Test` vs using the following code `if (test is MathTest) test.question()`. So only within the realm of Kotlin, what is added cost between running that code 100 times, as specified by OP.