# Same multiple downcasts in equals; will they be optimised?

Tags: java, equals, downcast

I tend to write my equals method in Java as a one liner...

```
class Test {
   private String a = "";
   private Integer b = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   private Long c = Long.MIN_VALUE;

   public Test(final String a, final Integer b, final Long c) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Test && ((Test) obj).a.equals(this.a)
          && ((Test) obj).b.equals(this.b)
          && ((Test) obj).c.equals(this.c);
   }
}
```

As you can see, in this approach I downcast the Object instance to Test instance many times. My question is, will it be optimised by the compiler so there will be a single downcast instead of three like if I wrote my equals method like this?

```
 public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof Test) {
         final Test test = (Test) obj;
         return test.a.equals(this.a) && test.b.equals(this.b)
           && test.c.equals(this.c);
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

It is not a duplicate of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165246/is-there-any-runtime-cost-for-casting-in-java) in comment, because I am interested here in brevity of the implementation of the equals method (6 lines against 3) but not at cost of a performance degradation. In the other question the difference is one line.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165246/is-there-any-runtime-cost-for-casting-in-java) with an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2165276/5064389).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I decompile the class I find that the Eclipse compiler and `javac` indeed produce three `checkcast` instructions in the `equals` method, so no optimization takes place.

When optimized by Hotspot it could be that hotspot can figure out that one cast is enough.

The decompiled byte code:

```
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
   Code:
      0: aload_1
      1: instanceof    #13                 // class sov/Test
      4: ifeq          62
      7: aload_1
      8: checkcast     #13                 // class sov/Test
     11: getfield      #3                  // Field a:Ljava/lang/String;
     14: aload_0
     15: getfield      #3                  // Field a:Ljava/lang/String;
     18: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
     21: ifeq          62
     24: aload_1
     25: checkcast     #13                 // class sov/Test
     28: getfield      #7                  // Field b:Ljava/lang/Integer;
     31: aload_0
     32: getfield      #7                  // Field b:Ljava/lang/Integer;
     35: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/lang/Integer.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
     38: ifeq          62
     41: aload_1
     42: checkcast     #13                 // class sov/Test
     45: getfield      #12                 // Field c:Ljava/lang/Long;
     48: aload_0
     49: getfield      #12                 // Field c:Ljava/lang/Long;
     52: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/Long.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
     55: ifeq          62
     58: iconst_1
     59: goto          63
     62: iconst_0
     63: ireturn
```

Comment: That's interesting but keep in mind that Eclipse uses a JIT compiler and not the default javac. So that compiler might produce a different output.

Comment: @DavidtenHove edited the answer, actually also javac of JDK 8 produces three checkcasts. Eclipse has no JIT compiler its just a replacement of javac

Comment: Would you mind posting the decompiled code here?